# Upload a video to firebase using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to pick a video from the camera roll and then uploading that video to firebase storage. So far I am able to pick a video but it is not uploading to firebase, how can I upload it to firebase storage?

```
func uploadVideoToDB(url: URL){
        let storageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child("video.mov")
        storageReference.putFile(from: url)

}

func fetchVideos(section: Int){
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]

        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){
    
        let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL")] as? NSURL
        DataService.instance.uploadVideoToDB(url: url! as URL)
        
        imagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this function to upload the video to firebase storage

```
func uploadTOFireBaseVideo(url: URL,
                                  success : @escaping (String) -> Void,
                                  failure : @escaping (Error) -> Void) {

    let name = "\(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)).mp4"
    let path = NSTemporaryDirectory() + name

    let dispatchgroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchgroup.enter()

    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let outputurl = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(name)
    var ur = outputurl
    self.convertVideo(toMPEG4FormatForVideo: url as URL, outputURL: outputurl) { (session) in

        ur = session.outputURL!
        dispatchgroup.leave()

    }
    dispatchgroup.wait()

    let data = NSData(contentsOf: ur as URL)

    do {

        try data?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .atomic)

    } catch {

        print(error)
    }

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("Videos").child(name)
    if let uploadData = data as Data? {
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil
            , completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    failure(error)
                }else{
                    let strPic:String = (metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!
                    success(strPic)
                }
        })
    }
}
```

Following function converts the video to mp4 format so that it can be viewed on any device either it be iOS or android

```
func convertVideo(toMPEG4FormatForVideo inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, handler: @escaping (AVAssetExportSession) -> Void) {
    try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL as URL)
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL as URL, options: nil)

    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
    exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        handler(exportSession)
    })
}
```

Comment: im getting this error ```Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'``` on this line ```let strPic:String = (metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!```

Answer (score 1):

This is what did it for me:

needed to convert `url` into `Data` then use `putData` instead of `putFile`

```
func uploadVideoToDB(url: URL){
        let filename = UUID().uuidString
        let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child("videos").child("\(filename).mp4")
        do {
            let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            ref.putData(videoData)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```